# MS SQL issue with result set column returning more than 4000 characters

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
select top 500 ID,
(DATA1+DATA2) as DATA 
from TABLE1
```

DATA1 has 3000 Characters and DATA2 has 4000 characters

Expected output  DATA1+DATA2 = 7000 characters

Current result is DATA1+DATA2 = 4000 characters

Comment: What is the data type of your `DATA1` and `DATA2` columns?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit is the data type of your field. You most likely have `NVARCHAR(4000)` as the type, which will truncate anything after 4000 characters. You'll need to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to get your desired output. This can be done at the table level or by casting

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
ID int, 
DATA1 NVARCHAR(4000), 
DATA2 NVARCHAR(4000), 
DATA3 NVARCHAR(MAX), 
DATA4 NVARCHAR(MAX)
)


INSERT INTO @table
values 
(1, REPLICATE('X', 4000), REPLICATE('X', 3000),REPLICATE('X', 4000), REPLICATE('X', 3000))

SELECT 
LEN(DATA1 + DATA2), -- will be not 7000 due to 4000 char limit
LEN(CAST(DATA1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(DATA2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), -- will be 7000 due to new type
LEN(DATA3 + DATA4) -- will be 7000 due to fields already have the max type
FROM @table
```

Comment: LEN(CAST(DATA1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(DATA2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) function worked for me